# How to close p-dropdown on p-dialog close?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I have an angular component consisting of ngprime p-dialog. In the body of this dialog there is p-dropdown. When I click on dropdown options are shown, but there is situation that user accidentally can click on closing dialog. The second time when dialog is opened, the dropdown options are available after double click, because the onHide event is executed on first click. Is there any way to close p-dropdown options on closing the dialog? Here's code

**HTML**

```
<p-dialog #dialog [closeOnEscape]="closeDialog" [responsive]="true" [modal]="true" [(visible)]="shown" styleClass="modal"
          [maximizable]="false" [baseZIndex]="1000" minWidth="200px" [width]="669"
          (onHide)="hideModal()" [draggable]="false">
  <p-header class="modal__header">{{category.name}}</p-header>
  <div class="modal__subcategory">
    <p-dropdown #dropdown  placeholder="Choose a sub-category" 
      [options]="subcategories" optionLabel="name [(ngModel)]="selectedSubcategory">
    </p-dropdown>
  </div>
</p-dialog>
```

**TS**

```
export class SuggestionsComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    category: CategoryDTO;
    @Input()
    shown: boolean;
    @Output()
    onHideModal: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
    subcategories: SubcategoryDTO[];
    selectedSubcategory: SubcategoryDTO;
    newQuestion: string = '';

    constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService, private surveyService: SurveyService,
        private toastNotificationService: ToastNotificationService,
        private internetConnectionService: InternetConnectionService,
        private loadingService: LoadingService) {
        this.onHideModal = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        if (this.category.id != null) {
            this.categoryService.getSubcategoriesByCategory(this.category).subscribe(
                subcategories => {
                    this.onHideModal.emit(true);
                    this.subcategories = subcategories.value;
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.internetConnectionService.showToastWhenErrorOccurred(error, " get subcategories");
                }
            );

        }
    }

    hideModal() {
        this.shown = false;
        this.newQuestion = "";
        this.selectedSubcategory = null;
        this.onHideModal.emit(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your .ts code as well. May be with some dummy data for testing

Answer (score 1):

`p-dropdown` has a method `focus()` you can call it after your modal was opened. (Use the `onShow()` Event of your `p-dialog` to call the

**Controller**

`onModalShow()` Method

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';


@ViewChild('dropdown') dropdown;

onModalShow() {
    this.dropdown.focus();
}
```

**Template**

```
<p-dialog #dialog [closeOnEscape]="closeDialog" [responsive]="true" [modal]="true" [(visible)]="shown" styleClass="modal"
        [maximizable]="false" [baseZIndex]="1000" minWidth="200px" [width]="669"
        (onHide)="hideModal()" [draggable]="false" (onShow)="onModalShow()">
<p-header class="modal__header">{{category.name}}</p-header>
<div class="modal__subcategory">
    <p-dropdown #dropdown  placeholder="Choose a sub-category" 
    [options]="subcategories" optionLabel="name [(ngModel)]="selectedSubcategory">
    </p-dropdown>
</div>
</p-dialog>
```

Comment: You were right about the (onShow) event on dialog but the solution demanded using hide() function (this.dropdown.hide()). Thanks for help :)